# Area percentage(%) is not appearing while using legend in dojo pie chart

Tags: charts, dojo, dojox.charting

I am using Dojo 1.6 to generate pie chart.

while i am using legend in pie chart, the slice percentage (%) is disappeared. and if i remove the legend code from the chart code slice  % is appears.  But i needs to show both.
How can both of these (% and legend) will appear in the same pie chart.

the chart without percentage,look like as...

[image]

code to create Legend...

```
       new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({ 
                 chart : chart,
                 horizontal : true
                 }, "legend2");
```

Comment: This issue is resolved by fixing the div tag for chart and Legend in the same order(first for chart than legend)...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, is not about the legend widget, the problems is with the data you used.

In order to display the percent values, you need to define the legend text like this:

```
var chartData = [
    {x:1,y:5,legend:"Income"},
    {x:1,y:10,legend:"Outcome"},
];
```

With this data, the percent values will be calculated and displayed on the chart, and the legend widget will display the proper labels